# Django: TemplateView or FormView?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I am currently trying to bring my function-based view into a class-based view. The question I am currently struggling with is if I should either trying to move it into a TemplateView with FormMixin or in a FormView with ContextMixin. Do you have any tips on how to decide what's best?

```
def event_detail_view(request, event, organizer):
    queryset = Event.objects.filter(organizer__slug=organizer)
    event = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=event)
    tickets = collect_all_tickets(event, organizer)
    ReserveFormSet = formset_factory(ReserveForm, formset=BaseReserveFormSet, extra=0)
    formset = ReserveFormSet(
        initial=tickets,
        # Example [{'ticket': "Early Bird"}, {'ticket': "Regular Ticket"},]
        form_kwargs={'organizer_slug': organizer}
    )
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ReserveFormSet(
            request.POST,
            initial=tickets,
            form_kwargs={'organizer_slug': organizer}
        )
        if formset.is_valid():
            order_reference = unique_order_reference_generator()
            for form in formset:
                ticket_name = form.cleaned_data['ticket'].name
                int_or_empty = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
                qty = is_int_or_zero(int_or_empty)
                if qty > 0:
                    obj = form.save(commit=False)
                    obj.ticket_name = ticket_name
                    obj.order_reference = order_reference
                    obj.save()
            return redirect('organizers:index', organizer=organizer)

    ticket_status = {}
    ticket_status['sold_out'] = TicketStatus.SOLD_OUT
    ticket_status['on_sale'] = TicketStatus.ON_SALE

    return render(request, 'events/event_detail.html', {
        'event': event,
        'formset': formset,
        'ticket_status': ticket_status,
        'tickets': tickets
    })
```

Comment: [`FormView`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/) already uses `ContextMixin`, you don't have to "use it with" `FormView`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class-based-views are not automatically better than function-based-views. If you have a function-based-view, then think carefully about whether you want to convert it to a class-based-view.

Django's generic CBVs are not designed for formsets. I often see people trying to process formsets in `UpdateView` or `CreateView` and in my opinion it leads to complicated code that is difficult to understand.

If you must use a class based view to handle your formset, you might want to look at [`django-extra-views`](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views) which contains some views you might find useful.

Comment: I concur with using `django-extra-views` in this case if you decide to go the CBV route, I was just about to post the same answer myself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Alasdair. It helped me to decide not using the CBV.