# why home.html (for adding a new post) is not showing the rendered django form with ckeditor toolbar in add new post?

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, ckeditor

i am integrating some apps to make a bigger project but the problem is when i try insert ckeditor in html login page it is not showing. for this reason i tried to make separate app is to see whats going on here. i am showing you the code in detail.

editing/settings.py:

```
..........
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'editor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'ckeditor',
]
TEMPLATES = [
    {

        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],........
.....................
STATIC_URL = 'editor/static/'
STATIC_ROOT='editor/static/'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH='editor/static/media/'
```

editing/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('editor.urls')),
    path('ckeditor/',include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

in this case, my static folder is in editor/static when i execute python manage.py collectstatic and ckeditor folder is in editor/static directory also.

editor/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body=models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    description=RichTextUploadingField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

editor/admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

when i execute **python manage.py makemigrations** and **python manage.py migrate**, ckeditor can be seen in **locahost:8000/admin**'s new post section perfectly. then i tried to make templates.

base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
<title>Django blog</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400"
rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'admin/css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<header>
<div class="nav-left">
<h1><a>Django blog</a></h1>
</div>
</header>
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

home.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>New post</h1>
<form action="" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ form.media|safe }}
    {{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

and then i have created a html file editor/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import HomePageView

urlpatterns=[
    path('',HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

and here is the editor/views.py also:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .models import Post


class HomePageView(TemplateView):
     model=Post
     template_name='home.html'
     fields=['title','body']
```

i just want to see a simple page of showing new html post editor with ckeditor toolbar in it. it's just for seeing what's wrong and why my ckeditor toolbar is not showing in my html file. when i run python manage.py runserver there is no error showing and the html page is showing django post and new post and only the save button. it can't render the form of the django's new post. css style is rendered because the django post and new post has the desired color and font. but why it is not rendering the new post form with ckeditor toolbar?

i am still learning and this problem is eating me up. thanx in advance

Comment: Based on your description, it looks like the whole form is not rendered. You did not have anything with the form itself in your HomePageView. maybe you should try to use function-based-view for this purpose. see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857793/django-templateview-or-formview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved it at last. the correct codes are given below:

for models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    #body=models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    description=RichTextUploadingField()
```

in views.py file, my mistake was that i called TemplateView which should be createView and this change will render the form on the front page. in HomePageView class, fields should be like ['title','description'], not with 'body'. rests are same and after migrate and runserver, the form displays the ckeditor. views.py becomes:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .models import Post


class HomePageView(CreateView):
     model=Post
     template_name='home.html'
     fields=['title','description']
```

thanx anyway....